Removed NuGet package and can't reinstall it in UE5 C++ project
I encountered an issue with updating NuGet packages in my Unreal Engine 5 (C++) project using Visual Studio 2022. While trying to solve it, I removed the Blake3 NuGet package. After managing to update the other packages, I ran into a new problem: compilation errors related to the missing Blake3.
Now I am getting the following errors:
The type or namespace name 'Blake3' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to install the Blake3 package using Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, but I ended up getting errors indicating that the installation failed.
Can I remove all NuGet packages and reinstall them? If so, how can I do this? Or is there a way to restore only Blake3? All the packages were previously installed automatically.
I am a beginner, so I am not sure what steps to take. I have attached a screenshot from the Error List for reference. If you need any additional details, please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
enter image description here

I managed to solve the problem by simply updating Unreal Engine. After the update, all errors were resolved, and the Blake3 package installed without any issues.
